# How to solve crash: Dns.java okhttp3.Dns$1.lookup?

Tags: android, retrofit2, crash-reports, crashlytics-android

recently I started to receive such crashes. Nothing was updated to have suspenders. Does anybody knows what can cause this issue? Thanks.

**com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:**

**retrofitVersion = "2.6.1";
retrofitConverterGsonVersion = "2.6.1";
retrofitAdapterRxJava2Version = "2.6.1"**

```
    Dns.java line 39
okhttp3.Dns$1.lookup

Fatal Exception: io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException
com.companyname.data.service.retrofit.exception.RetrofitException: Unable to resolve host "api.companyserver.com": No address associated with hostname
io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError (RxJavaPlugins.java:349)
io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservablePublish$PublishObserver.onError (ObservablePublish.java:187)
io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.checkTerminated (ObservableObserveOn.java:276)
io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.drainNormal (ObservableObserveOn.java:172)
io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.run (ObservableObserveOn.java:252)
io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run (HandlerScheduler.java:109)


Caused by com.companyname.data.service.retrofit.exception.RetrofitException
Unable to resolve host "api.companyserver.com": No address associated with hostname
com.lampa.letyshops.data.service.retrofit.adapter.RxErrorHandlingCallAdapterFactory$Rx2CallAdapterWrapper.asRetrofitException (RxErrorHandlingCallAdapterFactory.java:75)
com.lampa.letyshops.data.service.retrofit.adapter.RxErrorHandlingCallAdapterFactory$Rx2CallAdapterWrapper.access$000 (RxErrorHandlingCallAdapterFactory.java:41)
com.lampa.letyshops.data.service.retrofit.adapter.RxErrorHandlingCallAdapterFactory$Rx2CallAdapterWrapper$1.apply (RxErrorHandlingCallAdapterFactory.java:62)
com.lampa.letyshops.data.service.retrofit.adapter.RxErrorHandlingCallAdapterFactory$Rx2CallAdapterWrapper$1.apply (RxErrorHandlingCallAdapterFactory.java:59)
io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableOnErrorNext$OnErrorNextObserver.onError (ObservableOnErrorNext.java:91)
retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable$BodyObserver.onError (BodyObservable.java:72)
retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallExecuteObservable.subscribeActual (CallExecuteObservable.java:55)
io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe (Observable.java:10955)
retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable.subscribeActual (BodyObservable.java:34)
io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe (Observable.java:10955)
io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableOnErrorNext.subscribeActual (ObservableOnErrorNext.java:38)
io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe (Observable.java:10955)
io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableMap.subscribeActual (ObservableMap.java:33)
io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe (Observable.java:10955)
io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn.subscribeActual (ObservableObserveOn.java:45)
io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe (Observable.java:10955)
io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDoOnEach.subscribeActual (ObservableDoOnEach.java:42)
io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe (Observable.java:10955)
io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableMap.subscribeActual (ObservableMap.java:33)
io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe (Observable.java:10955)
io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableRetryWhen$RepeatWhenObserver.subscribeNext (ObservableRetryWhen.java:150)
io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableRetryWhen$RepeatWhenObserver.innerNext (ObservableRetryWhen.java:127)
io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableRetryWhen$RepeatWhenObserver$InnerRepeatObserver.onNext (ObservableRetryWhen.java:167)
io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$MergeObserver.tryEmit (ObservableFlatMap.java:262)
io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$InnerObserver.onNext (ObservableFlatMap.java:559)
io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableCreate$CreateEmitter.onNext (ObservableCreate.java:67)
com.lampa.letyshops.data.manager.UnauthorizedManager.lambda$new$0 (UnauthorizedManager.java:61)
com.lampa.letyshops.data.manager.-$$Lambda$UnauthorizedManager$b3aT2iQy6aaX0AixSwB-wvEbg4w.subscribe
io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableCreate.subscribeActual (ObservableCreate.java:40)
io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe (Observable.java:10955)
io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$MergeObserver.subscribeInner (ObservableFlatMap.java:162)
io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$MergeObserver.onNext (ObservableFlatMap.java:139)
io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.drainNormal (ObservableObserveOn.java:200)
io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.run (ObservableObserveOn.java:252)
io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ExecutorScheduler$ExecutorWorker$BooleanRunnable.run (ExecutorScheduler.java:260)
io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ExecutorScheduler$ExecutorWorker.run (ExecutorScheduler.java:225)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
```

Comment: this is most probably a connection problem, have you checked your connection to the api?

Answer (score 3):

If the server is OK (and most probably yes)
So this is a normal exception thrown whenever there is a problem in mobile conectivity. I think you should catch the exception and alert the user to check his connection.
please check this issue reported in okhttp repo
https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3919

Answer (score 1):

The crash log explains the issue for you. If we take a look at the following line:

> RetrofitException: Unable to resolve host "api.companyserver.com": No address associated with hostname

This means that the url you specified: `api.companyserver.com` does not exists (which is determined by a DNS lookup).

See the following:

```
$ ping api.companyserver.com
ping: cannot resolve api.companyserver.com: Unknown host
```

You should try calling another url, e.g. `stackoverflow.com` and it should work again.

To fix the crash, you might want to take a look in your `onError()` body where you make the network call, otherwhise you will need to catch the `UndeliverableException` or `RetrofitException`.

Comment: Thanks, but my host "api.companyserver.com" is usually working. I just wrote here wrong one, not to show company name.

Comment: Are you using proguard/minify for your app?

Comment: yes I am using proguard...can you explain how does it affect the network call?